# Achartengine: reverse y axis, how to do?

Tags: reverse, achartengine

I'm using achartengine to show graph, but I want to reverse the y axis for example from 15 up to 0. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed just to add:

```
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer aRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    aRenderer.setYAxisMin(15);              
    aRenderer.setYAxisMax(1);
    aRenderer.setYLabels(15);
```